# 64 bit chrome beta OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, google-chrome, 64-bit

Apparently Chrome Beta for OS X is supposed to be 64 bit.
(e.g. http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/08/29/chrome-38-beta-arrives-new-user-switching-profiles-guest-mode-64-bit-default-mac/

I have the latest Chrome beta Version 38.0.2125.77 beta but it is still 32 bit. I have reinstalled.

The dev channel is 64 bit on my Macbook Air (2013).

Answer (score 1):

Downloading this [Google Chrome 64-bit](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=mac&extra=devchannel) version 39.0.2171.2 - you get the correct one.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that the dev channel is 64 bit (see my post). The Chromium blog promises that the beta channel should also be 64 bit, but it's not.